# Let $D$ be a distribution. Show that every point of $p \in M$ has a submanifold $N$ such that $p \in M$ and $T_p N = D_p$.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

Let $D$ be a distribution. Show that every point of $p \in M$ has an embedded submanifold $N$ such that $p \in M$ and $T_p N = D_p$.

**Attempt**: Assume $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m$ and $D$ is a rank $k$-subbundle of $\pi: TM \to M$.

Let $p \in M$. Somehow, we will have to construct an embedded submanifold $N$ of dimension $k$ such that $D_p = T_p N$.

How can I construct such an embedded manifold? Any hints will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can proceed as Christopher Gadzinski indicated in his answer. Here is another approach.

Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on $M$. For each $v \in T_pM$ there is a unique geodesic $\gamma_v$ with $\gamma_v'(0) = v$. There is a connected open subset $U \subseteq T_pM$ with $0 \in U$, such that if $v \in U$, then the geodesic $\gamma_v$ is defined at $1$. The exponential map at $p$, denoted $\operatorname{exp}_p : U \to M$, is given by $\operatorname{exp}_p(v) = \gamma_v(1)$. If $r$ denotes the injectivity radius at $p$, then $\operatorname{exp}_p : B(0, r) \to M$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image. As $B(0, r)\cap D_p$ is an embedded submanifold of $B(0, r)$ of dimension $k$, then $N := \operatorname{exp}_p(B(0, r)\cap D_p)$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$ of dimension $k$.

It now follows that $T_pN = D_p$. To see this, first note that for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $tv \in U$, we have $\gamma_v(t) = \operatorname{exp}_p(tv)$. In particular, for every $v \in D_p$, there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\gamma_v((-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)) \subseteq N$. Therefore $v = \gamma_v'(0) \in T_pN$, so $D_p \subseteq T_pN$, but $\dim D_p = k = \dim T_pN$ so they are equal.

This idea is often used to demonstrate the relationship between sectional curvature and Gaussian curvature: if $P \subseteq T_pM$ is a two-dimensional subspace, then $\operatorname{sec}_p(P) = K_p(N)$.

Comment: I am not familiar with Riemannian metrics, geodesic and the exponential map unfortunately :(

Comment: If you could expand on the other answer, that would be great though!

Comment: Maybe you should give Christopher a chance to expand on his answer. I suggest you leave a comment on his answer, letting him know that there is now a bounty on the question.

Comment: This is the second bounty on this question. A month ago I also asked him to add more details to get the bounty, so I'm not really counting on an answer from his side this time...

Comment: haha, +1 for bringing the exponential map into it. This is of course equivalent to my answer if we take the pullback metric from a chart, but is able to avoid the talk of coordinates by appealing to the general existence of a global Riemannian metric. (This in is usually justified by patching together local coordinate metrics by through partitions of unity.)

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks for the answer. I accepted your answer because you tried to help me, but I gave the bounty to the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to find a submanifold that takes a certain tangent space at a certain point. You can do this when your manifold is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ trivially; just take a little piece of an affine space. Luckily, every manifold is locally diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

More specifically: let $\varphi\colon U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a chart of the manifold at $p$. Let $N$ be an embedded submanifold in $\varphi(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that takes the tangent space $(d \varphi)_p(D_p)$ at $\varphi(p)$. (For example, let $N$ be a restriction of an affine subspace.) Then, $\varphi^{-1}(N)$ is an embedded submanifold of $U$, and hence of $M$, that takes the tangent space $D_p$ at $p$. (To verify this, it is most convenient to regard an embedded submanifold as an inclusion map, and the tangent space "taken at a point" as the image of the differential of this inclusion.)

Comment: Kindly add some details, there is a nice bounty if you do so!

Comment: Sorry for the neglect of this question. I've added more details.

Comment: So, you claim that if $T_{\varphi(p)} N = (d\varphi)_p(D_p)$, then $T_p \varphi^{-1}(N) = D_p$?

Comment: And why is $\varphi^{-1}(N)$ an embedded submanifold of $U$? Is it because $\varphi: U \to \varphi(U)$ is a diffeomorphism and thus this sends embedded submanifolds to embedded submanifolds?

Comment: Here is how I understand your solution: Let $p \in M$ and take a chart $(U, \varphi)$ containing $p$. Let $N$ be an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $\varphi(U)$ with the property that $(d \varphi)_p(D_p) = T_{\varphi(p)}N$. Then we see that $T_p \varphi^{-1}(N) = D_p$ and $\varphi^{-1}(N)$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$ and we are done. Is that correct?

Comment: An embedded submanifold is, by definition, associated with an inclusion map that is an immersion and a homeomorphism onto its image. By $\varphi^{-1}(N)$, we understand the embedded submanifold whose inclusion is the composition of $\varphi^{-1}$ after the inclusion of $N$. (This is fine, since $\varphi^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism.) The deal with tangent space is just an application of the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. And is my interpretation of your solution correct then?

Comment: Yes, looks fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I awarded you the bounty, but I will give the other answerer the accept. Hope you are OK with that.

Answer (score -4):

This is not always true there exist  distributions which are not integrable.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294276/a-strongly-non-integrable-distribution

Comment: Thanks! The question has a follow up question which says: Why isn't this a contradiction to the Frobenius theorem? The question does not say that $D$ is integrable?

Comment: Read carefully. The OP is asking only for a submanifold whose tangent space at *one* point agrees with the distribution.